# How can I fetch data and display it in NextJs 13 or above?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, csr

I am new to NextJS so the question might sound a trivial so please bear with me. So, basically I want to fetch data from a database and display it in the page at the first render and for that I am trying to use useEffect and useState hooks as follows.

```
"use client"
import axios from "axios"
import Link from "next/link"
import { useEffect } from "react"
async function ProductsComponent( ) {
    const [products,setProducts] = useState<any[]>([])
    useEffect(()=>{
        async function fetchProducts() {
             "use server"
            try {
                const productsresponse = await axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/productControllers`)
                if(productsresponse.status === 200){
                    setProducts(productsresponse.data.message)
                }else{
                    console.log("Failed to fetch Products")
                }
            } catch (error) {
                
            }
        }
        fetchProducts()
    },[])
    return (
      <div className=" flex flex-col">
        <h3>Product Name</h3>
        {
            products?.map(product=>(
                <div>
                    <h4>{product?.productName}</h4>
                 </div>
                </div>
            ))
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  export default ProductsComponent
```

but I get an error of:

**async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components.**

and if i remove the `"use client"`, I get an error of:

**You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.**

So how can I ever fetch data from database and render it in NextJS >=13 ?

I tried defining a separate server side function component that fetches data from database using useEffect and the compoentnt takes the product and setproduct as props and I  passed the component in anohter client component where we define states like product ,setProduct but I am still getting an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are two ways to render a page:**

- Client Side - client gets page & it makes api call & then sets data
  in page.
- Server side - server gets data & generates page & then sends it to
  the client.

  **Two solutions :**
- Client side rendering, make a component with `'use client'` at top of
  it & import it in your page.
- Server side rendering (make page on server & then send to client)

***Read these concepts, for more clarity:***

- **Server Components** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components
- **Using Server Components in Next.js** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#using-server-components-in-nextjs
- **Benefits of Client Rendering**
  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#benefits-of-client-rendering
- **'use client'** https://react.dev/reference/react/use-client
- **When to use 'use client'**
  https://react.dev/reference/react/use-client#when-to-use-use-client
- **Client Components** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components
- **Using Client Components in Next.js**
  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#using-client-components-in-nextjs
- **Rendering** :
  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering
- **Server and Client Composition Patterns** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns

**As you said**

> display it in the page at the first render

**So SSR would be the way to go, as it will generate page & send it to the client.** No Loading states, will be seen.

I'm using NextJS version : `13.5.4`

By default Next.js considers a component as Server Component. But when you use `use client` in a component  you make it as client component.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#using-server-components-in-nextjs

Hence it throws a error when u remove `'use client'` from a component which uses (useEffect,useState etc. as this are hydrated/calculated on client side).

You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.

**Here is code with both implementations.**

**Folder Structure :**

```
projectName
├── .gitignore
├── jsconfig.json
├── next.config.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── next.svg
│   └── vercel.svg
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── app
│       ├── api
│       ├── comp
│       │   └── ProductsList.js
│       ├── favicon.ico
│       ├── globals.css
│       ├── layout.js
│       ├── page.js
│       ├── products
│       │   └── page.js
│       └── products_clientside
│           └── page.js
└── tailwind.config.js
```

- **Server side rendering**

`loc\src\app\products\page.js`

```
import axios from "axios";

async function GetProducts() {
    let { data } = await axios.get('https://dummyjson.com/products')
    return data
}

export default async function ProductsPage() {


    let Products = await GetProducts();
    console.log("Data from API on Serverside :", Object.keys(Products));
    // console.log("Products on Serverside :", Products.products);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Products Page (Serverside Fetching)</h1>
            {
                Products

                    ?
                    Products.products.map((p, i) => {
                        return (
                            <p key={i}>{p.title}</p>
                        )
                    })
                    :

                    "Getting Products ...."


                // THIS LOADING STATE WILL NOT BE VISIBLE BECAUSE SERVER LOADS THIS WHOLE PAGE
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Explaination :**

- Server when renders this page, GetProducts() is called on server-side, server waits, gets data & generates the whole page & then finally sends to client.
- Client during this time of rendering, just sees a blank screen, loading indicator in browser.

**Output :**

- Go on route `http://localhost:3000/products`
- you will see data console.log() in terminal (there 2 console logs 1 is to show keys present in data, other is commented out )

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Client side rendering:**

- Make a component in comp folder.

**ProductsList Component**    `loc\src\app\comp\ProductsList.js`

```
'use client'
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const ProductsList = () => {

    async function GetProducts() {
        let { data } = await axios.get('https://dummyjson.com/products')
        console.log(data);
        SetProducts(data)
    }

    const [Products, SetProducts] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        GetProducts()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Products Page</h1>
            {
                Products

                    ?
                    Products.products.map((p, i) => {
                        return (
                            <p key={i}>{p.title}</p>
                        )
                    })
                    :

                    "Getting Products ...."

                // THIS LOADING STATE WILL  BE VISIBLE BECAUSE CLIENT LOADS A SECTION OF PAGE 

            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductsList
```

Now make a page `loc\src\app\products_clientside\page.js` & import ProductsList

```
import ProductsList from "../comp/ProductsList"
const page = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1> Product Page Other Way (Client Side Fetching)</h1>
            <ProductsList />
        </div>
    )
}
export default page
```

**Explaination :**

- Client gets the page, then useEffect runs & calls API, shows `Getting Products ....` & when it gets data sets it & shows.

**Output :**

- Go to url `http://localhost:3000/products_clientside`
- You will see `"Getting Products ...."` & also in console the data recieved from api
- Go in the Network tab in present beside the console, open this page, you will see `products_clientside` under Name, click on it & then on right hand side click on `Preview Tab` you will see page is rendered till
- Product Page Other Way (Client Side Fetching)
  Products Page
  Getting Products ....
  After that it Products state is set & rendered by client( client side rendering - browser does it)

> ***If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update***
> ***answer if necessary)***

Comment: This is probably the most detailed solution I could ever get and thank you so much for the time you spent answering this. I wanted to vote this as an answer but since I am new I can't. but I have one more question, in the SSR solution you suggested, will the GetProducts act like useEffect in case of CSR? and in the second solution you suggested, is it allowed to import CS component to SS component? any links to such information or explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: - *Will the GetProducts act like useEffect in case of CSR?*
Yes, server will call it on its side & then put that data in the page & send a rendered page to you. During this time browser, will show a loading & screen will be blank(white).

- *Is it allowed to import CS component to SS component?*
Yes, because CS component are the ones which can interact with browser APIs (local storage, geolocation etc.) & also events like click enter leave etc. happen on client side. So a component which needs this functionalities you make them client side component. 
 
*Read the links updated in Answer*

Comment: **Please read the answer again I have added explanations & links**

- In short:


In SSR, I'm generating whole page (page.js) on server & sending it to client.


In CSR, I have page (page.js), in it I imported a CS component. Now server will just make this page & send to client, after that client will make API Call & set data. Server basically does nothing to CS component client(browser) takes responsibility to render it.

**Please check the network tab to see the difference, & it will help you understand CSR & SSR.**

Comment: To mark answer for your question, click on tick mark present on left side of a answer, below Save option (near down arrow). Read stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Can I buy you a coffee, sir?