# Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, shadcnui, ffmpeg-wasm

I have been building an application with reference from a similar project.
The link to the original project is: https://github.com/benlhachemi/modifio
My project is: https://github.com/Anirban-Saha/Filio
Whenever I am trying to upload a image or any media to the drop zone I am getting the error but I cannot figure out why is it happening. Below I have added pictures for reference.
[image]
[image]
[image]
Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fetch data and display it in NextJs 13 or above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77380376/how-can-i-fetch-data-and-display-it-in-nextjs-13-or-above)

Comment: Didn't solve my problem or maybe I couldnt solve it, would you mind trying out the code?

Comment: https://github.com/Anirban-Saha/Filio/blob/main/src/components/ui/dropzone.tsx#L126 You use async in a client component. You can't do that.

Comment: Didnt fix the issue. Can you suggest some solutions?

Comment: Check the rest of your code. It is the same issue somewhere else